# C# custom Windows Forms base class and designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement the GUI part of a plug-in, which means that I have to inherit from a custom base class (which inherits from UserControl) included with the plugin assembly.

When implementing my own control, I would normally inherit from UserControl and going to the designer would be really straightforward (just double clicking on the solution explorer).

In order to be able to work with the designer, I do a first implementation using UserControl as base class.

The problem is that as soon as I change the base class into ApplicantTabControlPlugin (the custom base class provided by the plugin), I cannot open the designer for this control anymore. I.e., if I close the designer, it seems it is gone forever.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: When you say you are trying to implement the GUI part of a plug-in, is this a 3rd party plug-in?  Why are you now trying to override it? --- Let me put it another way, if you wanted to override the behavior of a textbox you would derive from Textbox but you would not expect to be able to open the designer of a Textbox and start messing around with the bits inside.  The same is true for someone else's user control.  As far as I am aware I have not heard of a 3rd party base class that acts like the UserControl class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
<SubType>Component</SubType>
```

to the project file entry of your base class.